# jquery simplemodal: move #simplemodal-container to 0,0 for printing?

Tags: jquery, css, printing, simplemodal

Our simplemodal alert div needs to be printable. The content itself should fit on the page fine in most cases, but I can't override the positioning in my print css to get it flush top/left for printing to avoid having the right side cut off.

It seems like I can change #simplemodal-container in my print css for everything but positioning.  I've tried to position it absolutely and turn off all padding and margins but nothing works: it still appears in the center as it does on the screen version.

Does anyone know a way to override this for media="print"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the overrides weren't working because #simplemodal-container has inline styles applied.  You could try the following solution (which unfortunately won't work on IE <= 6):

```
#simplemodal-container[style] {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```